# Can't find protected_areas.shp in qgis_sample_data or GIS database

Tags: qgis

I have just installed QGIS 3.10 and have unzipped the two sample files named in heading cannot find the files named in:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/introduction/preparation.html

and have searched online for `protected_areas.shp` and `exercise_data/shapefile/protected_areas.shp` ?

Comment: The data is where it is said it would be in the downloadable zip-file. Have you downloaded the sample data?

Comment: Download these datas : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data/archive/v2.0.zip (from [this section of the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/foreword/foreword.html#data))

Answer (score 1):

You should look at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/4147

TLDR: it says the data you look for are at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data/archive/v2.0.zip

Comment: Thank you both, I have v2.0 folder now and have found the data.